# why is fs.readFile returning void in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, file, asynchronous

I'm new to node,js,typescript and NPM as a whole, I need a certain funtionality in a discord bot I'm building and only sdk I found to get it is in typescript which is a whole new world for me,
I'm trying to read a file using fs.readFile
here is the code:

```
import { readFile } from "fs";
import { Connection, Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { getOrca, OrcaFarmConfig, OrcaPoolConfig } from "@orca-so/sdk";
import Decimal from "decimal.js";

//console.log('test');
const main = async() => {
    const secretKeyString = readFile("lp.json", (error, data) => data);
    const secretKey = Uint8Array.from(JSON.parse(secretKeyString));
    const owner = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);
}
```

I'm getting a problem:

```
Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

ik that the function is async but I'm not familliar with asyncio in javascript so how can I resolve this?

Comment: I’d resolve it by (a) becoming familiar with async, and (b) searching for “nodejs read file as string. There’s no way forward but through.

Comment: yes, that's my go to thing. just got no option but use an sdk I'm not familliar with rn but thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use readFileSync here as it will serve the purpose you need in that context.

```js
import { readFile } from "fs";
import { Connection, Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { getOrca, OrcaFarmConfig, OrcaPoolConfig } from "@orca-so/sdk";
import Decimal from "decimal.js";

//console.log('test');
const main = async() => {
    const secretKeyString = readFileSync("lp.json", {
        encoding: "utf-8",
    });
    const secretKey = Uint8Array.from(JSON.parse(secretKeyString));
    const owner = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);
}
```

Comment: thx errors removed when I used the Sync version

Answer (score 1):

`readFile` is asynchronous and it gets the file contents in a callback. You can put your code in callback to fix.

```
const main = () => {
  readFile("lp.json", (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      const secretKeyString = data;
      const secretKey = Uint8Array.from(JSON.parse(secretKeyString.toString()));
      const owner = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);
    }
  });
};
```